# Get a certain part of a changing string

Tags: php

I have this:

```
"https://example.com:443/commonauth/?sessionDataKey=2aeeaf42-83d8-4b90-b8b4-39c1856c7de2&type=oauth2"
```

Now what I want from that string is only the sessionDataKey.
How do I extract that part from the string if the length of the string is different every time?

Comment: You get string, then you extract the sessionDataKey from the string Or you  will get the url then get the sessionDataKey?

Comment: i get the string and i want to extract de sessionDataKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get sessionDataKey from the string then you can do it this way

```
<?php
    $string = "https://example.com:443/commonauth/?sessionDataKey=2aeeaf42-83d8-4b90-b8b4-39c1856c7de2";

    preg_match("/sessionDataKey=([a-z0-9\-]*)(&|$)/", $string, $result);

    echo $result[1];
```

**([a-z0-9-]+)** - match 1 or more characters from a-z, all numbers from 0-9 and a dash

**(&|$)** - after previous match comes character & or the end of the string

If you want to get sessionDataKey from your URL then you can do it this way

```
<?php
    $sessionDataKey = $_GET['sessionDataKey'];

    echo $sessionDataKey;
```

This is a classic way of getting parameters from the URL. More about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).